# Find the first match without repeating the function call and creating extra variables. Is it possible at all?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, dry, computation

I would like to get the first successful result out of the function A which internally calls function B and C in order.

The key point here is - DRY. Which means I don't want to introduce new variable (e.g. to hold the result-state of the previous function call - see bad example #1), I do not want to repeat my action (e.g. call the same function twice - see bad example #2).

The example code is in PHP but I am not addicted to PHP, any language is acceptable. OOP, functional, does not matter here.

The concepts I found so far that may lead to the solution is the use of Maybe ( https://marcosh.github.io/post/2017/06/16/maybe-in-php.html ), some also suggested using nil ( https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#nil ) as the return type. However, I do not have the sufficient working example yet. And I wonder if this solution is possible at all, I even started to read the book called "Annotated Turing" hoping to find some links to the problem or limits in there...

Bad example #1 (extra variable):

```php
A() {
  $B = B();
  if($B !== null) {
    return B();
  }
  return C();
}
```

Bad example #2 (extra call):

```php
A() {
  if(B() !== null) {
    return B();
  }
  return C();
}
```

The key point here - DRY:
- I do not want any extra variables introduced (bad example #1).
- I do not want any of function to run twice (bad example #2).

Is such code without repeating the call and/or saving the state into extra variable possible to write at all?

If yes - I would like to see it. If not then I would like to have a valid proof this is not possible to write at all.

Comment: In PHP you can use `or`. `return B() or C();` but it will check only for truish values. Or maybe a null coalescing operator would work too.

Comment: Why the `algorithm` tag?

Answer (score 2):

This is for PHP 7 or higher using the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
<?php
function a()
{
    return (b() ?? c());
}

function b()
{
    return null;
}

function c()
{
    return 'result from c';
}

var_dump(a());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show examples in JavaScript because I'm more familiar with it. These are going to be our `B` and `C` functions:

```
function B() {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'B' : null;
}

function C() {
    return 'C';
}
```

### 1. Relying on short-circuit evaluation of logical `or`

```
function A() {
    return B() || C();
}
```

Note that this is a little bit different from what you want, because the result of `B()` will only be returned if it's a non-falsy value.

### 2. Using a utility function

```
function firstNonNullResult(functions) {
    for (const f of functions) {
        const result = f();
        if (result !== null) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

function A() {
    return firstNonNullResult([B, C]);
}
```

### 3. Using lazy evaluation

Some languages, such as Haskell, do not evaluate expressions until their result is needed, which allows you to write something like `find isJust [B, C]`, where `C` would only be evaluated if `B` returns nothing.

In JavaScript or PHP you can achieve a similar effect using generators.

```
function* map(items, fn) {
    for (const item of items) {
        yield fn(item);
    }
}

function find(items, predicate) {
    for (const item of items) {
        if (predicate(item)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
}

function call(fn) {
    return fn();
}

function A() {
    return find(map([B, C], call), x => x !== null)    
}
```